# Bootstrap Carousel Event Listiner Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adjust the intervals between carousel slides by using js to update the timeout using the following code:

```
**var t;
var start = $('#carousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
t = setTimeout("$('#carousel').carousel({interval: 3500});", start-3500);
$('#carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   
     clearTimeout(t);  

     var duration = $(this).find('.active').attr('data-interval');
        alert("slide event");

     $('#carousel').carousel('pause');
     t = setTimeout("$('#carousel').carousel();", duration-3500);
})**

As you can see, I even added and alert to let me know the code was invoked, but it never is and I don't know why.

I even added the following code in an attempt to confirm the slide.bs.carousel event but to no avail:

**$('#carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    console.log('slide event!');
    alert("invoked");   
});**


The html looks like this:

**
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">

    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item" data-interval="3000">
            <img src="image2" />
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-interval="6000">
            <img src="image3" />
        </div>
        <div class="item" data-interval="9000">
            <img src="image1" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>**
```

Can anyone please tell me what it is I am doing wrong here?

Thank you....

Rick

Comment: could you tell me what is wrong? seems fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/4L3p1fqv/

Comment: Well, the java script is not being invoked so the different slide intervals never change - just remains  the initial 3500ms. The javascript code is never invoked for some reason.  It is as if the event listener is not working but I don't see the problem.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you started(initiated) the carousel, the correct way to reset interval should be:

```
$('#carousel').data("bs.carousel").options.interval =  500;
```

```js
var t;
var start = $('#carousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
t = setTimeout(function() {
  $('#carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3500
  });
}, start - 3500);

var counter = 0;
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {

  counter++;
  console.log('interval -> ' + counter*500);
  $('#carousel').data("bs.carousel").options.interval = counter * 500;
})

$('#carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  console.log('slide event!');
  // alert("invoked");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work - and works fine, I might add, but it effects the overall carousel.  I was trying to target the timing for each individual slide, and the solution I tried is the most common used, however, it is failing in my development because the java script to do so is not being invoked - almost like a listener failure of some sort.

Comment: @Texson not sure I get what you mean but check the updated one.

Comment: Yes.  It works PERFECT, and so elegantly.  Thank you so very much for resolving this for me.  It is truly appreciated - and so is your sharing of expertise and knowledge.  Also, I appreciate the lesson you have taught me through your code.  Excellent.

Comment: @Texson Welcome to stackOverflow! If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!~~~~~ good luck coding!

Comment: This was the final version of the code I ended up using:

Comment: var counter = 0;

$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  
  var delay = $('#carousel').find('.active').attr('data-interval');
  counter++;
  console.log('slide:' + counter);

  console.log('set delay to -> ' + counter + ': '  + delay);  

  $('#carousel').data("bs.carousel").options.interval = delay;

  console.log('<----- end of ' + counter + '  ------->');    
})

$('#carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {

});

Comment: Can't figure out how to format the code - anyway, added a 'data-interval' property to each slide item and it worked out great.